# Check by Knight NxC3+ Move Implications

Tags: analysis, kings-gambit, eco

Here is the game I played which belongs to `ECO C34`. I would like to know Check NxC3+ implications. I couldn't cut the Knight. In which are the ECO games this NxC3+ can arise. Thanks for your comments and analysis in advance.

Here is the PGN.

```
[fen ""]
[Event "Live Chess"]
[Site "Chess.com"]
[Date "2017.01.12"]
[White "anandsadasivam"]
[Black "keviano7"]
[Result "0-1"]
[ECO "C34"]
[WhiteElo "643"]
[BlackElo "667"]
[TimeControl "600"]
[Termination "keviano7 won by checkmate"]
[CurrentPosition "rn3k2/ppB2bp1/8/3p1B2/1b1P2P1/7P/PPP5/R2Kq3 w - - 0 20"]

1.e4 {[%clk 0:09:59]} e5 {[%clk 0:09:50]} 2.f4 {[%clk 0:09:53]} exf4 {[%clk 0:09:13]} 3.Nf3 {[%clk 0:09:43]} Nf6 {[%clk 0:09:04]} 4.Nc3 {[%clk 0:09:35]} Bb4 {[%clk 0:08:51]} 5.d4 {[%clk 0:09:28]} O-O {[%clk 0:08:43]} 6.Bxf4 {[%clk 0:09:25]} Re8 {[%clk 0:08:28]} 7.Bc4 {[%clk 0:09:17]} Nxe4 {[%clk 0:08:20]} 8.Ng5 {[%clk 0:09:06]} Nxc3+ {[%clk 0:08:16]} 9.Kd2 {[%clk 0:08:00]} Nxd1+ {[%clk 0:08:11]} 10.Kxd1 {[%clk 0:07:59]} d5 {[%clk 0:07:22]} 11.Bd3 {[%clk 0:07:32]} f6 {[%clk 0:06:53]} 12.Bxh7+ {[%clk 0:07:27]} Kf8 {[%clk 0:06:36]} 13.Nf3 {[%clk 0:07:07]} Bg4 {[%clk 0:06:08]} 14.h3 {[%clk 0:06:27]} Bh5 {[%clk 0:05:37]} 15.g4 {[%clk 0:06:18]} Bf7 {[%clk 0:04:41]} 16.Nh4 {[%clk 0:06:09]} f5 {[%clk 0:04:31]} 17.Bxf5 {[%clk 0:05:59]} Qxh4 {[%clk 0:04:22]} 18.Bxc7 {[%clk 0:05:29]} Re1+ {[%clk 0:04:09]} 19.Rxe1 {[%clk 0:05:17]} Qxe1# {[%clk 0:04:05]} 
0-1
```

For reference here is the FEN.

```
[FEN "rn3k2/ppB2bp1/8/3p1B2/1b1P2P1/7P/PPP5/R2Kq3 w - - 0 20"]
```

Comment: You forgot about the safety of your king, so you got checkmated.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your question, but I'm considering to since you really shouldn't call Horse a Knight.

Comment: All this time I didn't see `Rook` which gave the actual check. Board interpretation or eye sight problem :(

Comment: is this `pgn` notation what I posted, I'm not sure, however `Rook` I am seeing newly, question is what else if it wasn't. With it question is merely vague.

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure what you are asking. This is not a question of any eco or opening but rather of tactics which you were missing. After Nxc3+ (discovered check), you lose the queen and basically the game. There are two main themes in this game:

1. **pin**: of the knight on c3 by the bishop on b4; Therefore the pawn on e4 is not protected anymore as you cannot move the knight
2. **discovered check**: These are in 99% of cases deadly as the piece which moves out of the way (in your case the knight on e4) can capture a piece  or attack a stronger piece (in your example both happens as black first captured on c3 and thereby attacked the queen on d1), while you have to deal with the check first and cannot recapture or secure your stronger piece.

If you practice tactics (which you should particularly as a beginner playing an opening like the king's gambit which is very tactical) you will be more aware of these themes and will be able to avoid them in the future.

You should have prevented this earlier. For instance 6. Bxf4 seems unnecessary as this pawn would be very difficult to protect for black and would fall sooner or later anyway.

Instead I'd suggest 6. Bd3 and castling as soon as possible in order to get out of the pin of the c3 knight and also out of any problems on the e-file as in your game.

Answer (score 2):

After 4...Bb4 5. e5 makes Black look scattered. White mobilizes nicely after 5...Nh5 6.Nd5 Nc6 7.Bb5 Be7 8. 0-0 0-0 9. d4.

The problem with 5. d4 is it makes good on the Bb4 pin on the Nc3.  5... Nxe4 is possible immediately, instead of ...0-0. But even so, as in the game, after 5... 0-0, 6. Bxf4 is simply not paying attention to the e-pawn, and as suggested already, 6. Bd3, 6. Qd3, or even 6. e5 are better moves.

Tactically speaking, you should shy away from the King's gambit unless your tactics are tight and fast. Dropping a queen by move 9 tells me this is not so. Play to your strengths.