# Considering Scandinavian defense versus Dutch defense

Tags: analysis, scandinavian-defense, dutch-defense

If the game had played between to GM which game progresses to more steps if pgn notion tends more defensive approach with less blunders.

Just for recap

Scandinavian defense `ECO B01`

```
[fen ""]
1. e4 d5
```

Dutch defense `ECO A80`

```
[fen ""]
1.d4 f5
```

Both openings are quite unbalancing. Which opening would lead to a longer game, and why would this be so?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Steps, which one progress more steps considering defensive metrics.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, and also I don't see why you would mix Scandinavian with Dutch defense in one question as they are very different openings.

Comment: I am just profiling by comparing chess openings from one another, on which I'm curious on this two over here.

Comment: What are "steps" and what is "progressing steps" and what are "defensive metrics"?

Answer (score 5):

I am still not sure whether this answers your question, but: Scandinavian tends to lead to more open/tactical games while the Dutch tends to lead to more closed/positional games. If you want to profile openings I suggest to take a database and check game positions of master players around move 10-15 and see whether you like any of those positions.

But anyway (and this is not meant to be condescending; I know I wrote this before to one of your other questions): if you want to improve in chess forget about all those openings for the time being and focus on not losing pieces in one move. This will give you much better chess than if you learn some opening lines by heart, without understanding the ideas behind the openings. As a second step, learn some general principles (good, bad pieces, development, ...) At move 16 both players blundered their queen and worrying about opening theory at this level is-to be honest-a waste of time.

Comment: Yep! Thanks for suggestions. I shall be following it in.

Comment: However you Answer lacks perception, I really appreciate your effort! I see 33.* Rb4+ as blundered move, can't foresee as you see, anything further.

Comment: Would that says something rather Blundered,- like Desperado as you didn't mentioned about that.

Comment: Its a blundered move. I hope type of `pin` for Knight which is, tidily is, `one cannot cut the Knight by Pawn, if Knight put check and it is guarded.` Over and above if Queen Caught else as discussed in this topic `Nxc3+`,-
 [Discovered Check](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/16366/check-by-knight-nxc3-move-implications)

Comment: Was anticipating someone say something over here, much disappointed.

Comment: It depends on the dutch though. A leningrad dutch probably will be more tactical than a most scandinavians.